# ActionBar tabs don't wrap_content

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I writing an application that is running in 3.1, that uses an ActionBar with tabs. If I set the action bar background to an image that is the same as size as the screen the tabs divide the screen width equally.

If I don't set a background they will wrap_content.

I can't seem to find any documentation on if this is settable with the style element.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out if you set the background of the ActionBar programmatically instead of with a style element it will wrap_content on the tabs.

Comment: they should fix this or at least document it.